# Way to simulate running javascript in web browser through using javascript itself

Tags: javascript, web, browser, console, cors

So what I'm trying to do is load window.open a page except the page that opens lacks scrollbars so what I tried to do was:

```
var script = win.document.createElement('script');
script.text = "$('body').css('overflow', 'auto');";
win.document.body.appendChild(script);
```

and obviously I get the permission denied error because of CORS. Anyhow, so I try running:

```
$("body").css("overflow", "auto");
```

via the web browser console (firefox) and it works; the scrollbar appearing as expected.

So all in all, I was wondering if there was a way to simulate running $("body").css("overflow", "auto"); on the web browser through javascript to get the same effect, and thus bypassing the same-origin error/protocol

(I hope it wasn't too verbose/confusing :D)

Comment: So you're kind of asking if there's a way to "simulate" unlocking the front door to my house even though you don't have the key?

Comment: well if you want an analogy, the problem to me is like me being unable to send you a letter to your house, while being able to get into your house and verbally tell you the contents of my letter. :\

Answer (score 1):

If your code is sitting in another window or frame and your code comes from a different domain than the window you are trying to modify, then you cannot change that other window in any way.  The browser will simply not permit access.  You can't directly modify and you can't inject Javascript into it.

That is a very important security protection and there is no way around it from plain Javascript in a web page.

If the other page wishes to cooperate with you, then you can use `window.postMessage()` to communicate with it, but that takes two cooperating pieces of Javascript, one in your window and one in the target window in order to effect a change.  If the other window is not your code and does not have a cross origin interface for making changes, then you can't use `window.postMessage()` with it.

Comment: So I'm guessing what happens when I write javascript via the web browser is that it registers it as the same domain so it runs, correct?

And there's no way to simulate this effect?

Comment: When you write in the console of the window from that particular page, you are IN that page.  There is no way to simulate that other than a browser plug-in which you would have to convince the user to install.  The console may also not be subject to the same protections since a page itself can't inject into the console, only an actual user can and an actual user can bring up the console in any page so there's no real reason to prevent access from the console.

Comment: If I were to have the page run in an iframe, could I do some tricks to get what I want? Or is it still impossible?

Thanks in advance.